# Maintain app id

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, office-365-developer

I am developing an SharePoint Add-in (ex. app) from Visual Studio targeting Office 365.
I've registered this app in Azure AD (there is app!) and on ReplyUrl I've wrote the url obtained when I first debug this app

```
https://mytenant-7fc76d95b16303.sharepoint.com/MyOutlookCalendar/Pages/Default.aspx
```

Worked fine a couple of times then VS changed that ID of my app and it's not recognized anymore by Azure AD.
I can add this new url to Reply Url but I don't think this is a solution.
Sometimes I can't change it in Azure AD and I am forced to delete the app and configure it again.
Any ideas how to work with this kind of projects ?